# Mongoengine collection naming with UpperCamelCase?

Tags: mongoengine

I have been adding some collections to a Flask app using mongoengine models and the code works fine.
I was inspecting the data using MongoCompass and just noticed that one of the collections is named **notify_destination** which is NOT the name I used or its lowercase version.

My model class is  **NotifyDestination** and there is no meta tag - so why the underscore in the middle of the collection name?

```
class NotifyDestination(me.Document):
    owner_id = me.ObjectIdField()
    username = me.StringField()
```

Mongoengine documentation (2.3.4) just says
*The name of the collection is by default the name of the class, converted to lowercase*.

Is insertion of the underscore normal behavior of MongoEngine because of my using UpperCamelCase?

I still have time to specify & force a name using a meta = {} tag in the model if this behavior is not officially documented somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(mongoengine contributor here) Yes, this is the default behavior, the doc is imprecise but it's basically converting from UpperCamelCase to snake_case.

This means that

```
class User(Document):
    # will have "user" as default collection name

class MyCompanyUser(Document):
    # will have "my_company_user" as default collection name

class USACompany(Document):
    # will have "u_s_a_company" as default collection name
```

Note that the doc was fixed.